# Java - MouseListener on JPanel isn't firing

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jpanel, mouselistener

I have a `JPanel` using `BorderLayout` which has 2 components. A `JLabel` in the `NORTH`, and a `JList` in the `CENTER`.

I've added a `MouseListener` to the panel and for the moment coded a messagebox to appear on `mouseEntered`.

The problem is the event is only triggered if the cursor enters the area occupied by the label. I need the event to fire when the mouse enters the whole panels area.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit: Code to create the panel**

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
p.add(new JLabel("Label"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
p.add(new JList(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
p.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entered Panel");
        }
        //Other overriden methods
        ...
    });
```

Comment: "*Let me know If I need to display some code.*". Yes, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: *"Code to create the panel"*  Which part of SSCCE are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: So you want a full program? Can you recommend how I upload it for downloading.

Comment: Who asked for a *full program*?  Did you even read the link?

Comment: BTW - note that the `JList` will consume mouse events.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I do believe that the component with the highest z-index accepts MouseEvents first, and if they do nothing, they (usually) pass them on. So, if your JList is in your JPanel, it will have a higher z-index and since the JList handles the event, it is not passed on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the JList is the component which receives the mouse event. I'm not sure this is the best way to deal with the problem, but couldn't you add the same mouse listener to the JList as well?

Answer (score 4):

As of jdk7 you can decorate any JComponent with a JLayer and register the layer to receive all events dispatched to its children, something like

```
    JTable list = new JTable(30, 5);
    JComponent panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));
    panel.add(new JLabel("we are label"));
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    LayerUI<JComponent> ui = new LayerUI<JComponent>() {

        @Override
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JComponent> l) {
            if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED) {
                System.out.println(e.getSource().getClass() + " at " + e.getPoint());
            }
        } 
    };
    JLayer<JComponent> layer = new JLayer<JComponent>(panel, ui);
    layer.setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK );
```

Note that this is internally handled by an AWTEventListener, just as solution suggested in Rob's blog. The advantage over Rob's solution is that it will work in sandboxed contexts as well (as a core class JLayer has the necessary priviledges).

For earlier jdk versions, there's a [project JXLayer](http://jxlayer.java.net) (part of SwingLabs) which is the direct predecessor of the new core class. It doesn't have the permission issues because it internally uses a slightly different approach to get hold of all the events.

Answer (score 0):

Any component that has a MouseListener will receive the mouse event and it will not get passed to the panel.

You could add a MouseListener to every component but what if the design of your panel changes. Don't forget you probably have a scrollbar on the right of your JList so if the user enters the panel from the right the event would not be generated until the mouse is moved over the scrollbar onto the list.

Instead you might want to consider using a [Global Event Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) to listen for mouseEntered events. Then when an event is received you need to check if the source of the event is the panel itself or a child component of the panel. You should be able to use:

```
SwingUtiltities.isDescendingFrom(...)
```

to help with this check.